# Why is Outlook preview pane showing HTML, not text?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I have an HTML email which is showing up in Outlook's preview pane, displaying just the first bits of text content from that email.

However for some of my colleagues, it's showing some of the HTML.  e.g. if my email content looked like:

```html
<html>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="http://www.example.com/spacer.gif">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                This is a test
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

My preview pane looks like this; it correctly displays me the first bit of text content from the email body:

[image]

However for other users, they're seeing this; it's for some reason outputting what looks like HTML markup, i.e. it's output inside `<...>` angular brackets, and it's grabbing the source of the first image it finds, before it then correctly gets the text content that follows it.

[image]

I want to know what the setting is in Outlook that's affecting this.  I've tried switching my view to show 1, 2 or 3 lines to no affect.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't find an answer to **why** it was showing the HTML for some users. However I did find a solution to **how** to prevent it happening.

I found some old blog articles which suggested various things.  e.g. adding any desired text as an alt attribute on a 1px gif at the top of the email:

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2006/10/optimizing-for-gmails-snippets/

```html
<img src="http://www.example.com/spacer.gif" alt="Hey just testing">
```

Or using a hidden `<span />` like this:

```html
<span style="display:none !important">Hey just testing</span>
```

These worked fine for me, but still not my colleagues.  However, as part of my testing, I signed up to [Litmus](https://litmus.com/), and found this in the source of the emails they started sending me:

```html
<!-- HIDDEN PREHEADER TEXT -->
<div style="display: none; mso-hide: all; width: 0px; height: 0px; max-width: 0px; max-height: 0px; font-size: 0px; line-height: 0px;">
    Press save and watch your screenshots refresh instantly. It’s like magic! 
</div>
```

I assumed they knew what they were doing, and it seems to work.